# center border-right in 3 column layout

Tags: html, css

I am working with a 3 column layout that has a 5.5% margin right set. When i try to add border-right to the first two columns it looks very uneven on the count of the 5.5% margin. Is there a way to center the border between the columns?

CSS for the columns is as follows:

```
et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column_1_3 {
width: 29.666%;
}

et_pb_gutters3 .et_pb_column {
margin-right: 5.5%;
}

.et_pb_column {
float: left;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `margin-right: 5.5%`, try `margin-right: 2.75%` and `margin-left: 2.75%`.

Comment: I tried but the 3rd column doesnt fit. The 5.5% margin come from the grid that the theme came with so there might be something else at play here. I will keep digging. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Try to post enough code in your question so we can reproduce the problem. We will be able to help you more that way.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered splitting the 5.5% margin between margin-right and margin-left?  That way it forces half of the margin to the column to the right of the column you are having an issue with.

```
margin-right: 2.75%;
margin-left: 2.75%;
```